# Object with multiple functions with optional arguments in another thread

Tags: multithreading, lambda, pyqt, keyword-argument

I have a worker object, which has many functions and I'll like to use them on an extra thread. So, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37837008/6850241) answer and it works if I pass a fixed number of arguments to the functions, more or less like this:

```
    _signalCommand = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    self._signalCommand.connect(self.nanomax.test)
    self._signalCommand.emit('testA', 'testB')
```

But in my case, I can't use a fixed number of arguments. I need optional ones, my functions are like this:

```
 def test(self, test1='test1', test2='test2'):
    print test1
    print test2
```

So, in order to fix that I was using lambda, like this:

```
    _signalCommand = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    self._signalCommand.connect(lambda: self.nanomax.test('testA', 'testB')
    self._signalCommand.emit()
```

Doing this way, indeed, fix my optional arguments problems but it makes the object running in the main thread. I think this is because lambda creates another function and is like calling the worker directly (`self.nanomax.test('testA', 'testB'`) as mentioned in the answer I previously shared.

Is there anyway to avoid this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the case you describe here, where you have two optional arguments and you know their value in advance, I do not see any problem. Just create a signal `_signalCommand = QtCore.pyqtSignal()` and another one `_signalCommand2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)` connect them both and emit whichever you like depending on if you want to use the default values or not.

Comment: The thing is that in my program I need got get all optional arguments coming from a list. This list would bring me any number of parameters with any values.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use partial for this

eg :

```
from functools import partial
...

_signalCommand = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    self._signalCommand.connect(partial(self.nanomax.test, 'testA', 'testB'))
    self._signalCommand.emit()
```

Comment: Thanks, it seams it is working but the only problem is that I can't pass the list values using the unpacking operator like this: `self._signalCommand.connect(partial(self.nanomax.test, *self.arg[1:]))`, is there another way to do that? Pass as many arguments as the list goes?